# SFTP server for Windows with its own users and folders?

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, openssh

anyone knows if there's a SFTP server for Windows, with these features?
1. sftp users db is separate from windows users (preferably a simple text file with user/password pairs or some kind of db with gui). I just don't like the idea of creating a full windows user to only use it for file transfers
2. for each user I can specify a home folder manually (could be on different disks)
3. free (as non-paid)

I tried OpenSSH, but it seems to be tied to windows users. Judging by how much time it took me trying to set it up, it would take a lot of time to check all other existing server software so I decided to ask.
As for what I am trying to accomplish - I am trying to set up a server to sync with winscp. Plain FTP is out of question as it's not encrypted, FTPS/ES data connections are blocked by firewall, SFTP utilizes single port and is allowed on our firewall. The problem is, I am too used to filezilla server which had it's own user db and could set specific home folders for each of them, so I want to have the same functionality with SFTP

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com//help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: How many users do you need? AFAIK, Bitvise WinSSHd allows 5 virtual users in the free version.

Comment: All of the standalone SSH servers for windows are very old and outdated. I think you may struggle to find anything that suits your requirements, + is free, + is not ridiculously old and buggy. By far the most reliable, secure way I've found to run an SSH server on windows is with cygwin. This may be a bit heavier duty than you're looking for, but it is well maintained, and robust. It does however use Windows users. I don't think you'll be able to get around this.

Comment: Hopefully SSH support will be added natively to Windows in the not too distant future. It apparently is in progress.

Comment: OpenSSH for windows is hopelessly out of date now, and as you've noticed, very tedious to setup. I seriously wouldn't bother with it. Cygwin is easier to setup, and much more stable.

Answer (score 0):

As **grawity** suggested, Bitvise WinSSHd is the closest answer.

I can create users, set specific permissions for all of them, map virtual directories similar to FTP.
In future I may even use it instead of filezilla server, since SFTP requires less network access to be usable.

Free version limits are fine for personal usage.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at [Syncplify.me Server!](http://www.syncplify.me/products/server/), which indeed has a user database that's separated from the Windows user database (although it can also integrate with Windows and AD, but only if you want to), and comes with several license types, including a free one.