# FreSSHd User Home Directory

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server-2008, sftp, freesshd

Using Win Server 2008 R2.

I have one user named `jim` setup in freeSSHd. The SFTP home path is set to `C;\`. This works fine.

I have now created an additional user named `john`, I would like to set their home path to `C:\john`.

Is this possible?

Ideally I would like numerous, separate SFTP user accounts. Each with access to only specific folders.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do not use FreeSSHD. It's not maintained for years => Not safe to use.

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl Any other suggestions?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1034565/213663

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this,

1. Change the user authentication for all your user to NT server's Authentication.
2. Select the SFTP tab and change the Home Path to `$PATH\`.
3. Create a local user on the Windows server, making sure to select the **Password Never Expires** checkbox and click Save.
4. If you'd like to use a different user path, right-click on the newly created user, and select the properties option.
5. Select the Profile tab and modify the Profile Path and Local Path fields to your desired folder. For example, for user Alice, the Profile Path should be `c:\SFTP\alice\` and Local Path should be `c:\SFTP\alice`. Remember to terminate the Profile Path with a **\**